# Div follow as you scroll on desktops screen and is fixe on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I want a div follow as you scroll when you are on a screen wider than 991. On a screen size smaller i want the div fixe. And i want the javascript code refresh every time someone load or resize the page.

Here my code (it's not dry...).

My problem is when i resize the window (desktop screen -> mobile screen -> desktop screen...):
1 - on mobile screen i can't go at the bottom of the page
2 - on desktop screen i have a problem when i scroll the page

```
  //when the page is load and the window resize detect if it's a smallscreen
  var smallscreen = true;
  $(window).on("resize load", function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 991) {
      smallscreen = false;
    }
    else {
      smallscreen = true;
    };

    //if it's not a small screen activate the scrolling
    if (smallscreen == false) {
      $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(window);

        $window.scroll(function(e){
          if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
          }
          else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 180
            });
          };
        });
      };
      $('#checkout_validation').followTo(400);
    }
    else {
      $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(window);

        $window.on("resize scroll load", function(e){
          if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'initial',
                width: '100%',
                top: 0
            });
          }
          else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'initial',
                width: '100%',
                top: 0
            });
          };
        });
      };
      $('#checkout_validation').followTo(0);
    };
  });
```

Comment: You could remove code for smallerscreen and just use the CSS to position it fixed. And for desktop move the `$.fn.followTo` function out of `$(window).on("resize load"`. And similarly move other codes as well. This will give you clear idea what is not working.

Comment: @iMatoria Thank you for your answer. If i remove the smallerscreen code the div will always scroll if i resize the window.

Comment: That is what you have to manage using CSS. You could add a class in case of smallscreen and than use CSS. This is very general way of implementing mobile first code/html.

Comment: Thank you @iMatoria , i finalized a working code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working code. Thanks you @iMatoria for having dried it.

```
//when the page is load and the window resize detect if it's a smallscreen
var smallscreen = true;

$.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.on("resize scroll", function(e) {
        function positionByScreen(positionForBiggerScreen, topOffsetForBiggerScreen) {
            if (smallscreen == false) {
                //alert('bigcreen scroll end');
                $this.css({
                    position: positionForBiggerScreen,
                    top: topOffsetForBiggerScreen
                });
            } else {
                //alert('smallscreen no scroll end ');
                $this.css({
                    position: 'inherit',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        }

        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            positionByScreen("absolute", pos);
        } else {
            positionByScreen("fixed", 180);
        };
    });
};

$(window).on("resize load", function() {
    smallscreen = !($(window).width() > 991);

    //if it's not a small screen activate the scrolling
    $('#checkout_validation').followTo(smallscreen ? 0 : 400);

    //var d = document.getElementById("checkout_validation");
    //d.className += " otherclass";
});
```

Comment: @iMatoria i just figured out a problem in the code. When i first load the page on a mobile the element parameter is (position: fixed;
    top: 180px;) and i need to resize or scroll to have the correct parameters apply. I tried to add "load" on the line 5 but it's not working. ($window.on("resize scroll", function(e))